# jquery hover event not working properly

Tags: jquery

I have a simple horizontal menu and when I hover each one of the items a sub menu slides down. So basically it is a typical navigation menu that we see so often. I want that when hovering the sub menu slides down and up when mouse out. My problem is that if I move the mouse so fast through the items it happens that more than one sub menu stays visible. I guess it's because the slide down was not finished when I trigger the slide up. Some idea to prevent this? Heres my code:

```
        $('#menu > li').hover(
                function () {
                    $('ul',$(this)).slideDown();
                },
                function () {
                    $('ul',$(this)).slideUp();
                }
            );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call [`stop`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/stop#clearQueuegotoEnd) before sliding up and down, and from your description, you should also pass `true` for both optional parameters like this:

```
$('ul',$(this)).stop(true, true).slideDown();
```

The first parameter (`clearQueue`) tells jQuery to clear the animation queue, stopping any queued animations.

The second parameter (`gotoEnd`) tells jQuery to complete the current animation. (This parameter might not be necessary in your case, depending on the effect you want.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification about the parameters of `.stop()`!!! I was using `.stop()` for a similar effect to this question and it was STILL glitchy until I passed true for both parameters as you suggested :)

Answer (score 3):

Before your slideUp you could probably use the stop() function to stop all current animations.

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/stop

Comment: You mean $('ul',$(this)).stop().slideUp();  ?
I tried this but then I have a weird behaviour. If I start moving the mouse left and right very fast the sub menus start to shrink :)

Answer (score 1):

what may be happening is that the mouseleave event isn't firing at all.  You could test that by adding some `console.log` statements to the start of the event handlers, and then checking IE8's Developer Tools or Firebug to see whether all the events are firing.

If you want to interrupt a running animation, [jQuery has a stop() method that does that](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/stop). You might also want to have each slideDown cause all the others to slide up.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your animation queue is getting built up with each time you enter and leave each li element.

Try out the [hoverFlow jQuery Plugin](http://www.2meter3.de/code/hoverFlow/)